# C++ vector sorting with my own Function

Tags: c++

```
Info:
Parent Class: Vehicle
Child Class : Car & Lorry
```

I got a vector and i trying to sort it by ascending area

sort(myVector.begin(),myVector.end(),compareByArea);

so at the Vehicle.h

I did

```
class VehicleTwoD
{
private:
//some variable
public:
bool compareByArea(const VehicleTwoD,const VehicleTwoD);
}
```

and at Vehicle.cpp i did this

```
bool VehicleTwoD::compareByArea(const VehicleTwoD &a,const VehicleTwoD &b)
{
return a.getArea() < b.getArea();
}
```

Error was VehicleTwoD has no member named getArea.

It is located in my child Car & Lorry and double area is also declare in the child .

But the issue is if i want to sort by this way, could i achieve it by using virtual and then I create the same method at child but overload it and get my area sort by that way

Is there a better way to do it .

**Thanks for all help!**

```
Additional Info:
```

I have this getArea() function at Car & Lorry which is just a simple

```
double Car::getArea()
{ return area;}

double Lorry::getArea()
{ return area;}
```

But now as i got a list of object in my vector, each of them is a child of different class. but all got getArea function, i want to sort this vector which is

```
sortVector.assign(vehicletwod, vehicletwod + arrayCounter);
sort(sortVector.begin(),sortVector.end(),compareArea);
```

//but the sort doesnt work.

I don't know where to create compareArea which can getArea() of object 1 against object 2 and return bool result;

I try to create it in VehicleTwoD using this

```
bool VehicleTwoD::compareByArea(const VehicleTwoD &a,const VehicleTwoD &b)
{
return a.getArea() < b.getArea();
}
```

But the issue is VehicleTwoD don't have the function getArea, they are located at child. how should i get this fix . Thanks..

**Thanks to the help:**

I tried the following

```
template<typename T> bool compareByArea(const T &a, const T &b) {
    return a.getArea() < b.getArea();
}
```

and i declare it at the .h file too,

```
public:
template<typename T>
bool compareByArea(const T,const T);
virtual double getArea();
```

then at my main.cpp i tried

```
sortVector.assign(vehicletwod, vehicletwod + arrayCounter);
sort(sortVector.begin(),sortVector.end(),sortVector[0].compareArea);
```

It give me an error

error request for member compareByArea in sortVector.std::vector<_TP, _ALLOC ....... which is of non class type 'VehicleTwoD*'

If i do this

```
  sortVector.assign(vehicletwod, vehicletwod + arrayCounter);
  sort(sortVector.begin(),sortVector.end(),sortVector[0].compareArea);
```

I will get error compareByArea was not declared in this scope.

What should i do? I declared compareByArea at VehicleTwoD which is included in main.cpp

VehicleTwoD is the parent class, and i also virtual double getArea() so when it call getArea it will use the child getArea instead, because the private variable - area is at child and the function getArea() return area is also at child

**What should i do.. confused & stuck.
Thanks!**

**Latest Update Again:**

I am trying to sort the vector by compareByArea which the smaller area will be sort at the highest while the bigger 1 will be at bottom.

The problem is getArea is a function of Car & Lorry (child class) and i create this compareByArea at main.cpp

sortVector is a vector copy of vehicletwod

The way i set value into my vehicletwod is this way..

```
if(vehicleType=="Car")
{
vehicletwod[arrayCount] = new Car();
vehicletwod[arrayCount].setDimension();
//set area
vehicletwod[arrayCount].setArea();
cout << "Done setting the data";
}
```

How do i achieve my sorting by area ascending.

I created this function at main.cpp

```
template<typename T> bool compareByArea(const T &a, const T &b) {
    return a.getArea() < b.getArea();
}
```

then i did this

```
sortVector.assign(vehicletwod, vehicletwod + arrayCounter);
sort(sortVector.begin(),sortVector.end(),compareByArea);
```

Compile Error:
Compile error:

```
no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<VehicleTwoD*>::iterator, std::vector<VehicleTwoD*>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'

note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort (_RAIter, _RAIter)
note: template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAiter, _RAIter, _Compare)
```

**Thanks**

I got a new compile error

```
error: passing 'const VehicleTwoD' as 'this' argument of 'virtual double VehicleTwoD::getArea()' discards qualifers.
error: passing 'const VehicleTwoD' as 'this' argument of 'virtual double VehicleTwoD::getArea()' discards qualifers.
```

Regarding my getArea is this

//in parent is this way

```
double VehicleTwoD::getArea()
{
double area;
area=0.00;
return area;
}
```

Car - Child is

```
 double Car::getArea()
    {
    return area;
    }
```

Comment: For one thing, your function signatures don't match. For another, does it actually contain `getArea`?

Comment: The error message is correct: `VehicleTwoD` does not have a member function named `getArea`. You can see that by looking at the definition. The fact that some other class has such a member function isn't relevant. So write the member function.

Comment: @user1595932 No, you must define `compareByArea()` outside of `VehicleTwoD` or make it `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a template function:

```
template<typename T> bool compareByArea(const T *a, const T *b) {
    return a->getArea() < b->getArea();
}
```

then you can pass it to sort:

```
sort(sortVector.begin(), sortVector.end(), compareByArea<VehicleTwoD>);
```

**Update:**

Vehicle.h:

```
class VehicleTwoD {
...
public:
    virtual double getArea() const;
};

template<typename T> bool compareByArea(const T *a, const T *b) {
    return a->getArea() < b->getArea();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<VehicleTwoD*> sortVector;
// fill sortVector
sort(sortVector.begin(), sortVector.end(), compareByArea<VehicleTwoD>);
...
```

Comment: Hi there, do i need virtual getArea at VehicleTwoD

Comment: Making it a template doesn't help anything, unless you also solve the real problem, which is that it shouldn't be a member (or should be static)

Comment: No, you need `getArea()` at `VehicleTwoD` or `T`.

Comment: I updated my question with what i just tried with your solution, Thanks for the help. but i still can't get it working.

Comment: @user1595932 Copy of my other comment: No, you must define compareByArea() outside of VehicleTwoD or make it static.

Comment: can you see my latest question update. it contain the error i face

Comment: @OlafDietsche , I did what you mention, then i compile it, it say main.cpp: error:  compareByArea was not declared in this scope

Comment: @user1595932 I updated and extended my answer. Please try again.

Comment: @OlafDietsche , I did the declaration at Vehicle.h , but when i compareByArea<VehicleTwoD> , it give me comparebyArea was not declared in this scope , expected priamry-expression before '>' token , expected primary express before ')' token

Comment: @OlafDietsche , I updated my question with the new error during compile.

Comment: Look at the modified template.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Tried your new template but still cant get it work error: passing 'const VehicleTwoD' as 'this' argument of 'virtual double VehicleTwoD::getArea()' discards qualifers.
error: passing 'const VehicleTwoD' as 'this' argument of 'virtual double VehicleTwoD::getArea()' discards qualifers.

Comment: @user1595932 `getArea()const` needs to be `const`. See modified answer.

Answer (score 3):

If `VehicleTwoD::getArea` is public, then the simplest thing to do is to make `compareByArea` a free function rather than a method of `VehicleTwoD`:

```
bool compareByArea(const VehicleTwoD &a,const VehicleTwoD &b) {
  return a.getArea() < b.getArea();
}
```

Then you can easily pass use it for sorting:

```
std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), compareByArea);
```

In C++11, you could use a lambda expression:

```
std::sort(std::begin(myVector), std::end(MyVector),
          [](const VehicleTwoD &a, const VehicleTwoD &b) {
            return a.getArea() < b.getArea();
          });
```

If `getArea` is not public, you could still use `compareByArea` as a free function, but declare it as a friend of the class.

**Update**:  A complete, working example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class VehicleTwoD {
  public:
    VehicleTwoD(double area) : m_area(area) {}
    double getArea() const { return m_area; }
  private:
    double m_area;
};

bool compareByArea(const VehicleTwoD &a,const VehicleTwoD &b) {
  return a.getArea() < b.getArea();
}

int main() {
  std::vector<VehicleTwoD> vehicles;
  vehicles.push_back(VehicleTwoD(3.0));
  vehicles.push_back(VehicleTwoD(1.0));
  vehicles.push_back(VehicleTwoD(2.0));
  std::sort(vehicles.begin(), vehicles.end(), compareByArea);
  for (auto it = vehicles.begin(); it != vehicles.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->getArea() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean free function

Comment: By "free function" I mean a function that's not a member of a class.

Comment: I'm sorry you're having such a difficult time with this.  I've added a complete example to my answer to illustrate the first option I gave.