# C++ Free Function . Vector Sorting & Issues

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ vector sorting with my own Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145370/c-vector-sorting-with-my-own-function)

C++ Free Function . Vector Sorting & Issues

I tried create a free function base on a response i receive recently from [1 of the experts here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145894/845092).

What i did was at my main.cpp

I created this function at main.cpp

```
template<typename T> bool compareByArea(const T &a, const T &b) {
    return a.getArea() < b.getArea();
}
```

I actually got this at my main.cpp

```
sortVector.assign(vehicletwod, vehicletwod + arrayCounter);
sort(sortVector.begin(),sortVector.end(),sortVector[0].compareArea);
```

There 1 parent class & 2 child class in my program

```
Parent: Vehicle
Child: Car & Lorry
```

Car & Lorry got a

```
private: 
double area;
public:
double getArea();
```

**What I am trying to Achieve**

I am trying to sort the vector by compareByArea which the smaller area will be sort at the highest while the bigger 1 will be at bottom.

The problem is getArea is a function of Car & Lorry (child class) and i create this compareByArea at main.cpp

sortVector is a vector copy of vehicletwod

The way i set value into my vehicletwod is this way..

```
if(vehicleType=="Car")
{
vehicletwod[arrayCount] = new Car();
vehicletwod[arrayCount].setDimension();
//set area
vehicletwod[arrayCount].setArea();
cout << "Done setting the data";
}
```

How do i achieve my sorting by area ascending.

Compile error:

```
no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<VehicleTwoD*>::iterator, std::vector<VehicleTwoD*>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'

note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort (_RAIter, _RAIter)
note: template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAiter, _RAIter, _Compare)
```

Thanks for all help!!

Comment: I'm sure that no "expert" asked you to place a template definition in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: `sort(sortVector.begin(),sortVector.end(),sortVector[0].compareArea);` makes no sense. Perhaps the third argument could be `&sortVector<VehicleTwod*>`, but then your types are wrong. So now you have to bind a dereference function too.

Comment: The "expert" who gave you that code failed to inform you that the `compareArea` function should _not_ be a member of the class.  Also, it was a lousy answer to the previous question you had.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of using a free function to sort with.  It doesn't mirror your class design exactly, mostly because it doesn't really make sense.  If you're going to store pointers to a base class then you're going to need to have the `GetArea` function available to be called from that base pointer.  It also doesn't make sense to have the area stored in each child if it is the same type, just put it in the base so you're not duplicating code.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle(double Width, double Height)
        : Area(Width*Height) {}

    double GetArea() const { return Area; }

private:
    double Area;
};

class Lorry : public Vehicle
{
public:
    Lorry(double Width, double Height)
        : Vehicle(Width, Height) {}
};

class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
    Car(double Width, double Height)
        : Vehicle(Width, Height) {}
};

bool CompareVehiclesByArea(const Vehicle* lhs, const Vehicle* rhs)
{
    return lhs->GetArea() < rhs->GetArea();
}

typedef std::vector<Vehicle*> VehicleVec;

void PrintVehicles(const std::string& Header, const VehicleVec& Vehicles)
{
    std::cout << Header << std::endl;
    for(size_t Index = 0; Index < Vehicles.size(); ++Index)
    {
        std::cout << "Index: " << Index << ", Area: " << Vehicles[Index]->GetArea() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    VehicleVec Vehicles;
    Vehicles.push_back(new Car(1.0, 2.0));
    Vehicles.push_back(new Car(3.0, 4.0));
    Vehicles.push_back(new Lorry(1.5, 2.5));
    Vehicles.push_back(new Lorry(3.5, 4.5));

    PrintVehicles("Before:", Vehicles);
    std::sort(Vehicles.begin(), Vehicles.end(), CompareVehiclesByArea);
    PrintVehicles("After:", Vehicles);

    //Cleanup omitted for brevity
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that you use vector of *pointers*, but access to objects via references in `compareByArea`. But its parameters are actually resolved to **references to pointers to objects**, not references to objects.

Correct way:

```
// Note - parameter types are pointers, not references
template<typename T> bool compareByArea(const T* a, const T* b)
{
   return a->getArea() < b->getArea(); // getArea() must be const!
}

typedef std::vector<VehicleTwoD*> VehicleTwoDVec;

// Old good way
sort(sortVector.begin(), sortVector.end(),
  &compareByArea<VehicleTwoDVec::value_type>);

// "Advanced" C++11 way
sort(sortVector.begin(), sortVector.end(), 
  &compareByArea<std::remove_reference<decltype(sortVector.front())>::type>);
```

But ask yourself twice - do you really need `compareByArea` to be template? It complicates things but doesn't solve any problem in your code.

Answer (score -1):

`sort(sortVector.begin(), sortVector.end(), sortVector[0].compareArea);` is incorrect.

You could fix it by switching to

```
sort(sortVector.begin(), sortVector.end(), &compareArea<decltype(*sortVector.begin())>);
```

A better fix would be to ask yourself if the template is necessary, since it would appear you're only ever comparing that one known type.

Comment: It just tell me compareByArea was not declared in this Scope.